# Who is the guy in the Picture in Naked Gun 2 1/2 "Blue Note" jazz bar scene?

Tags: naked-gun-2

In the 1991 movie [The Naked Gun 2 1/2: The Smell of Fear](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102510/), there is a joke I don't get. It's in the scene after Frank Drebin finds out Jane Spencer is going out with one Quentin Hapsburg. He gets depressed and heads to the "Blue Note" jazz bar. There are four pictures on the wall:

- The first is a street with the city behind on fire (I presume this is the San Francisco earthquake)
- The second is the Hindenburg
- The third is the Titanic
- The fourth is some guy who looks like [DA Jack McCoy from Law & Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBg3A.jpg).

Who is the fourth guy?

Comment: Funny to note. In the same scene, about 20 seconds later (what appears to be a continuity error, but I'm sure was done intentionally) the pictures are switched out(between Michael Dukakis & SF Earthquake?). The two new pictures are of a Ford Edsel and the Hubble Telescope. The Edsel, a Ford disaster of the late 1950s costing them millions. Hubble Telescope, initially a disaster when put into orbit until repairs to fix a flawed mirror were made.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Michael Stanley Dukakis.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dukakis#Election_defeat)

He was a US presidential nominee in 1988.

From the link above as well as the comment below, it details that he lost terribly to George H. W. Bush (The first President Bush) in that election. Seeing that the previous pictures, show disasters in which it was assumed the object in the disaster would succeed, the movie shows Dukakis as someone who experienced a great defeat though he went into election assuming otherwise.

[image: Michael Dukakis]